# IAR Idatastack error with CC2510

Tags: iar

I am using IAR with Texas Instruments CC2510.
I do not have any eval kit plugged in. When I try to "Debug without download", I get the following error when I try to run the code - "The stack pointer for stack 'IdataStack' (currently IData:0x07) is outside the stack range (IData:0xC0 to IData:0x100)"
Any idea how to solve this?
The debug is set to simulator. The correct device is selected under project options.

Answer (score 0):

Yo have selected to debug in the simulator without downloading the code that you want to debug.  There will therefore not be any code to take the simulated processor from its default power up state to the start of main.  Try debugging with download so that the simulator is initialised with the image that you want to debug.